# Inconsistent Tab Size in GitHub PR UI

Tags: github

Recently, I made a PR to a newly started open source repo in GitHub, where a collaborator pointed out that the tab size I used for *tabs* does not match the other PRs in that repo. I was confused because I preserved the orginal indentation as it'd been and furthermore, the indent style was not spaces but tabs.

Because the *Files changed* tab in my PR really had its `data-tab-size` attribute set to 8, while 3 other PRs had its `data-tab-size` set to 4, I thought there must be some reason behind it; I searched online and found that `.editorconfig` of the repo is responsible for the shown tab size; however, I did not modify that file; moreover, the files in my PR and the other PRs were of the same file type(markdown), in the same directory, and using tabs for the indentation for the code blocks.

I wonder what causes the peculiar inconsistency in the tab size in the PR UI.